# openfeint always offline?

Tags: openfeint

I have just downloaded the latest openfeint SDK: OpenFeint.2.10i

Then I build&&run the sample project on my itouch3 which is all ok.

I can get/set the data correctly.

Then I tried to close the wifi and then run the app. When I tried 
to submit a data, I got the message "new highscore, saved locally",
that is good.

But, when I turned on the wifi and then run the app again, I was not
back online, I am still offline!

There is no button to bring me back online anymore...???

Can someone help me? Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue where I would be online, debug my game, exit the app, and then never be able to get back online.  Very frustrating.

I found that deleting the app on the device would cause OF to go through the login process again and fix itself, but it is very annoying to have to do that every time I want to debug.

Chris.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. When the app starts, it go through the login process and LOG:

    User logged in, but OFFLINE. UserId: #######

Deleting the app on the device get the same result. *logged in, but OFFLINE*


Did you find any solution??
Any help??

I'm currently using framework 2.12.5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OpenFeint has now been permanently shut down:
https://twitter.com/OpenFeintStatus
http://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2012-11-19-gree-shutting-down-openfeint-on-december-14